# Using bootstrap with radio_buttons in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Is it possible to use the bootstrap radio buttons i.e:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">someValue</button>
```

with a form_for in rails?  There is a radio_button method:

```
    <%= radio_button("object", "method", "someValue") %>
```

, but I wasn't able to style it.  I didn't know if there is someway to merge the two to give the radio button the bootstrap appearance of the first snippet.
Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use like this,

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <%= f.radio_button :brand, "ABC", :id=>"first", :style=>"display:none;" %>
  <label for="first" class="btn btn-primary">First</label>

  <%= f.radio_button :brand, "PQR", :id=>"second", :style=>"display:none;" %>
  <label for="second" class="btn btn-primary">Second</label>

  <%= f.radio_button :brand, "MNO", :id=>"third", :style=>"display:none;" %>
  <label for="third" class="btn btn-primary">Third</label>
</div>
```

here you need to give id to radiobutton and can assign the label to it by using *for* attribute in label tag. So that it can indicate corresponding radio button.

Comment: Need to include NAME to properly associate radio buttons, unless I am missing something http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but if you set the *value* attribute of the label the same as the radio button params, it would work the same way as assigning an id for the corresponding radio button

```
<%= f.radio_button :brand, "MNO", :style=>"display:none;" %>
<%= f.label :brand, "Third", value => "MNO", class="btn btn-primary" %>
```